# PyCharm GitHub error "git@github.com: Permission Denied (publickey)"

Tags: github, pycharm, public-key-encryption, public-key

Ok about 2 hours ago I enabled the VCS as GitHub, then went in and did the Oauth (I think its called) where JetBrains opens a browser and asks me to authorize GitHub. Then I clicked admin, create a repo, add comments, add read comments, and other stuff to authorize PyCharm to create a repo and push via the app.

Now I'm still getting errors, it pushed to create a repo... but there is no code inside.

[image]

Why isn't this a simple process? I've enabled it, and setup GPG access but it refuses to sync my code.

Now under preferences>version control the directory just shows  despite my project having a name and over 500 files.

Under Preferences > Version Control > Github it shows my GitHub icon, I tried login in thru the IntelliJ button and I've synced a token. Neither worked

[image]

Pycharm is supposed to be a simple way to learn to develop stuff and be integrated.

What am I missing as I'm authorized on PyCharm Professional as a student.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I've since been able to connect to GitHub via ssh but still don't know how this setup is supposed to work with JetBrains PyCharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find how to fix this in pyCharm, but it worked for me when I saved my private key (matching the one authorized in GitHub) in my `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Hope it helps.